# I found an error which is wrong is FileNotFoundError in python

Tags: database, python-3.x

I want to import the dataset but fail because he has an error that is there for two \ i do not know how he was generated

```
import  pickle
import numpy as np
import os

def load_cifar_batch(filename):
    with open(filename,'rb') as f :
        datadict=pickle.load(f,encoding='bytes')
        x=datadict[b'data']
        y=datadict[b'labels']
        x=x.reshape(10000,3,32,32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype('float')
        y=np.array(y)
        return x,y

def load_cifar10(root):
    xs=[]
    ys=[]
    for b in range(1,6):
        f=os.path.join(root,'data_batch_%d' % (b,))
        x,y=load_cifar_batch(f)
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)
    Xtrain=np.concatenate(xs) #1
    Ytrain=np.concatenate(ys)
    del x ,y
    Xtest,Ytest=load_cifar_batch(os.path.join(root,'test_batch')) #2
    return Xtrain,Ytrain,Xtest,Ytest
```

and then i try to run

`import numpy as np
from data_utils import load_cifar10
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
datadir='E:\python\waa\cifar10\cifar-10-batches-bin'
x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test=load_cifar10('datadir')`
the error is
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:'datadir\\data_batch_1'`

There are two \ in my error,how to fix it?

Comment: The error is quite self explanatory. The path of the file is not correct. You need to debug your code and see what is the path that python is trying to open.

Comment: yes,you are right,I try to debug longtime,but I can't fix it,maybe i need some help.